# Unable to pass array value on YAxis in D3

Tags: d3.js

I'm unable to pass the whole array value in D3. Only first two values of array are appearing on the Y-axis. It featured on this page:https://digitalxlabs.com/d3-charts/rectangle-transition-part1.php

Username: DXLdemo
Password: View@098#

Here is the sample code I'm using:

```
               var ydata = [{"val":"0-9"}, {"val":"20-29"}, {"val":"40-49"}, {"val":"60-69"}, {"val":"80-89"},  {"val":"100+"}];
      //add x and y axis
               var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([0, 720]);

                var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .range([180, 0]);

                /*y.domain().tickvalues*/


                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(5)
                    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; });


                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(6)
                    .tickValues(ydata.map(function(d){return d.val;}));

                /*yAxis.tickValues([0-9,20-29,40-49,60-69,80-89,100]);*/
                /*yAxis.tickValues(ydata.map(function(d) { return d.val; }));*/

                x.domain([0,25]);
                /*y.domain(ydata.map(function (d) {return d.val; }));   */
                /*y.domain([10,100]);*/ 
                    /*.tickFormat(function(d,i){return d.ydat[i]});*/
/*                y.domain([]);*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are docs for d3 scales https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales.

You can't just write:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal().range([180, 0]);
```

You have to specify the domain. Also use rangePoints if you are passing the interval.

Try something like this:

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(ydata.map(function(d){return d.val;})).rangePoints([180, 0]);
```

Comment: Hi Sergeyz,

This only display the count of my array not the values inside it.

Comment: try var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(ydata.map(function(d){return d.val;})).rangePoints([180, 0]); Note that your domain will be an array of strings, when you are using "y" scale to position bars.

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thanks for this it worked perfectly. i had one more question, can you please help me in reducing the width of the axis, right now its too much thick, and doesn't suit to be featured on the website.
If you could help me with one last query it would be very great.

Comment: If you take a look at the axis in the chrome inspector elements panel, you'll notice that it consist of groups of lines and texts ( ticks ) and a path ( domain line ). You need to select lines and path and change their stroke-width property to something less than 1. ( selection.style('stroke-width', 0.5) ) or you can just change styling in .css file. Don forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

remove 'x.domain([0,25])' is not required. and add 'y.domain([0,150])'. you have not set domain to y axis. domain refers to minimum and maximum value of Y axis.

Comment: what does this suppose to mean? Can you please elaborate your code, or provide me some. As, I'm unable to get what exactly you are trying to say.
Thanks